# VBA to loop of various arbitary selected columns, find maximum value , save it in cell below each column

Tags: excel, vba

Data groups have multiple columns with all groups in an arbitrary location on sheet1.   Something like

```
Values for 1    Group 1     Values for 2    Group 2     Values for 3    Group 3
    4.3         Info            6.2         Info           4.3          Info
    3.2         Info            7.3         Info           3.2          Info
    6.2         Info              8         Info           6.2          Info
    3.5         Info                                       3.5          Info
                                                           4.45         Info
                                                           4.51         Info

Maximum value               Maximum value               Maximum value
```

For reasons unimportant to this, the block may be arbitrarily located on a work sheet and the various column lengths can change.  I highlight the data to select it and start the process.

I want to loop over all the data and find the maximum for each of the values columns and write it into a cell lower in the same column.

It is the arbitrary nature of the columns and rows that cause me the heart burn.  How reference them in the script.

Comment: Did you try recording your actions, and modifying the code? If so please update your question to include the relevant lines causing you issues. The arbitrary nature of the columns can only be resolved based on the pattern of your groups, for example a group always starts with a cell containing the text "Value for #", and it's a contiguous range of cells with data (can be navigated Ctrl-Up, Down, Left, Right), or "The group always ends at a cell containing text value "..."

Comment: Sorry Paul,  my first post.  How do I input a table in my question, that would make it easier.  Yes tried that but it doesn't deal with arbitrary positions, it hardwires the particular locations (cells) that I'm working with which can and do change as the data and info change.

Comment: I reformatted the sample data you provided - is that close to what you have? Also, is `Maximum value` in your file or you want to place the max val there?

Comment: Do these blocks have blank cells around them in all directions? In other words, does Ctrl-* or CurrentRegion select the whole block and nothing but the block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expects a 2 row gap between each group

```
Sub findValuesForGroups()
    Dim found As Range, adr As String, clr As Long, rng As Range, frm As String, lr As Long

    clr = RGB(222, 222, 222)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

      Set found = .Find(What:="Values for *", After:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            adr = found.Address
            Do
                formatCell found.Resize(1, 2), clr
                lr = found.End(xlDown).Row - found.Row
                frm = "=Max(" & found.Offset(1).Resize(lr, 1).Address & ")"

                If found.Offset(lr - 1).Value2 = "Max" Then
                    found.Offset(lr - 1).Resize(2, 1).Clear
                    lr = lr - 2
                    frm = "=Max(" & found.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lr, 1).Address & ")"
                End If

                found.Offset(lr + 1).Value2 = "Max"
                found.Offset(lr + 2).Formula = frm
                formatCell found.Offset(lr + 1).Resize(2, 1), vbYellow

                Set found = .FindNext(found)
            Loop While Not found Is Nothing And found.Address <> adr
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub formatCell(ByRef cel As Range, ByVal clr As Long)
    With cel
        .Interior.Color = clr
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

---

[image]

Comment: Yes that is general issue.  Only difference is that it might start anywhere, not A1.  I know how to locate start and end so I'll work from your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Paul!!  I'll update what I've started.  Sorry to be slow, I got too many balls in the air.  I will be back.

Comment: Paul, compiler syntax errors.  I put the coding into MS Vis Basic (v7.0).  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong - what version of Excel do you have, and what line of code gets highlighted when you see the error? You may also try to click menu "Debug" -> "Compile VBAProject" (do you get any errors doing that?)

Comment: Try removing the first line of code **Option Explicit** - in the same module you may have other undeclared variables and Option Explicit forces you to be disciplined and declare all variable used in all functions within the same module. If that doesn't solve the issue: what's the exact message (and description) in the error?

Comment: Thanks Paul.  A bad character hidden in the text.  I need to be more careful in my cut and past.  Works great!